# `setxkbmap kr` not doing anything?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, keyboard-layout, xkb, setxkbmap

I'm trying to add a configuration to my multilingual setup on my ArchLinux desktop, but Korean doesn't seem to do anything, despite it being listed under `setxkbmap`.

How do I set it up similarly to other languages?

So far, what I've been doing is basically this:

```bash
# For US International:
setxkbmap -layout us -variant intl

# Or for just US:
setxkbmap us
```

Why doesn't this work:

```bash
setxkbmap kr
```

Am I missing a (Pacman/AUR) package?

Comment: Since Korean is has more than 30ish elementary symbols, its common characters require more than one key stroke, so I think you need an input method. I'm not familiar with how that works. It might depend on your desktop environment.

Comment: The Korean keyboard layout is mappable on top of the typical ANSI one, they have their own alphabet, with a similar number of symbols, as you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_language_and_computers). It's even very common for Koreans themselves to switch back and forth between their layout and Roman characters, as they also sometimes have to type stuff with those characters.

Comment: Korean characters denote syllables and are composed from multiple parts (3 sounds in most cases, I think). That's not an alphabet (it's a syllabary), and the relevant aspect is that each character requires multiple keystrokes, unlike alphabetic languages where most characters require a single keystroke. As far as I know, this requires extra client-side software, not just an XKB configuration.

Comment: [Hangul is known typically as "the Korean alphabet"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul), but Wikipedia also describes it as a "syllabic alphabet". But anyways, I don't care about terminology. As long as someone is able to help with setting up the Korean keyboard, it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it doesn't work with `setxkbmap` because it's a different input method, instead of a layout. But I still don't have an explanation for why `kr` would be listed under `setxkbmap` then.

Anyway, setting up [`fctix`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fcitx) — or another [input method](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Input_method) such as [`uim`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Uim) — works perfectly, and there's a GUI tool with it, with shortcuts configurations.

Even though these links are broken, let me leave some video tutorials that might help here:

- [YouTube - Brodie Robertson - *Fcitx: Input Method Editor Made Easy On Linux*](https://youtu.be/lJoXhS4EUJs)
- [YouTube - Nice Micro - *International language input (European + Asian) on Arch Linux: FCITX*](https://youtu.be/GejGVDfuJQo)
- [YouTube - Nice Micro - *Let's use both a European and an Asian keyboard layouts simultaneously on Arch Linux*](https://youtu.be/NgYhSiZSk4A)